# Will deleting stuff from the Ubuntu partition (directly) increase free space on a Windows XP partition?

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem, windows-xp, delete

My system has dual boot: windows xp and ubuntu. Accessing files and directories of windows xp from ubuntu is easy as well known. I deleted some files and directories in windows xp, let say in c:\foo.bar from ubuntu. When I boot to windows xp, I expected some more free disk space after some delete from ubuntu, but the free disk space is unchanged as nothing happened, but deleted files and directories from ubuntu have all gone. Where is this space?

Thank you.

-Paul

Answer (score 4):

- Ubuntu and Windoze will (generally) be on different partitions.
- If you delete stuff on partition A, this will increase free space on partition A, but *not* on partition B.
- You'd need to repartition, e.g. with `gparted` (booted from CD), to materialize the gain in free space on partition B.

Answer (score 3):

This link might be of some help to you -

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoverLostDiskSpace